# Error running Swift in VS Code (windows 10)

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code, executable, new-operator

Can not run swift code in VS Code: giving error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q7Y3.png).

I have installed swift and LLDB extensions.

Very new to coding, so any help or question is appreciated.

Code and json screenshots below:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFvUi.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSMju.png)

```
var seasonName = 2
switch seasonName {
    case 1:
        print("winter")
    case 2:
        print("spring")
    case 3:
        print("summer")
    case 4:
        print("fall")
    default:
        print("there are only 4 seasons on Earth")
}
```

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<executable file>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried to reinstall VScode, restart pc, reinstall all extensions.